# Is Rehmannia safe for dogs? Is it effective for arthritis?

Tags: dogs, medicines, arthritis

Our 8 year old dog - a suspected doberman/labrador mix - has recently been diagnosed with arthritis in his back and rear legs. Our veterinarian has prescribed Rimadyl, which has seemed to help his movement some when we give it to him. However, he has had gastrointestinal problems (ongoing gurgling, diarrhea, etc.) when taking the drug. Furthermore, researching Rimadyl has us concerned about long term, irreversible effects to his GI system or liver, especially since he doesn't seem to tolerate the drug well.

A friend suggested Rehmannia, an herbal remedy that she said is safe and effective for treating canine arthritis. My friend referred me to a website to learn more about it, but the website discusses stuff like Qi, and balancing Yin & Yang; stuff I don't put much stock into. My own search attempts have turned up some reviews (mostly positive, but some negative ... and some irrelevant to our situation (i.e. treating other conditions)) of the product, but no clinical studies.

So, is Rehmannia safe for dogs? Does it effectively treat arthritis?

Answer (score 2):

Like many of the substances used in Traditional Chinese Medicine (TCM) Rehmannia (aka Rehmannia 8 or *Bawei Dihuang Wan*) seems to be credited by it's proponents with being able to treat/cure a [huge variety of ailments](http://www.itmonline.org/articles/rehmannia_eight/rehmannia_eight.htm) -

> - Nephritis (nephrosclerosis, nephrolithiasis, nephrotuberculosis), pyelitis (nephroatrophy), albuminuria, and edema.
> - Cystitis, cystolithiasis, cystotuberculosis, senile cystoatrophy, prostatomegaly, dysuria, urinary incontinence, and nocturia.
> - Diabetes and urinary incontinence.
> - Cerebral hemorrhage, arteriosclerosis, hypertension, and hypotension.
> - Neurasthenia, amnesia, nocturnal emission, uncontrolled emission, impotence, and inappropriate erection of the penis.
> - Lumbago, sciatica, deformed vertebra, numbness of the legs, and beriberi.
> - Cataract, glaucoma, decrease of eyesight, and keratitis.
> - Eczema, tinea, senile itching, vaginal itching, dry skin, and urticaria.
> - Chronic gonorrhea, rectoptosis, climacteric disturbance and related disorders.

As you can see arthritis isn't on that list and it has to be said I've never seen treating arthritis as one of it's claimed uses.

There seems to have been some clinical trial work done on Rehmannia-based treatments for atypical dermatitis in dogs: [Ferguson,*et al*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1365-3164.2006.00523.x) and: [Nagle *et al*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11906651) but I haven't come across much else. And to be honest I'm highly skeptical that it's effective for much of the laundry list of what it's claimed to be able to treat let alone things that it doesn't!

The fact that the two trials (for AD) linked above happened and the dogs..well didn't die, suggests that it's not inherently *dangerous* for dogs to consume (assuming appropriate dosing) but there seems little chance of it treating your dog's arthritis.

As for how you *can* treat them; Assuming it's osteoarthritis (as opposed to something like hip dysplasia) it's basically the same as it is for humans - anti-inflammatory painkillers (specifically ones intended for dogs, don't go giving them ibuprofen as it's toxic for dogs!), diet, physiotherapy and low impact exercise - [particularly swimming](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2014/459809/).

You (and your dog!) have my sympathies - osteoarthritis is a fecker! But it *can*  be managed to reasonable degree and much quality of life can be had.

Answer (score 1):

There are clinical studies I have seen of rehmannia, especially Canadian journal of medicine I think, rehemania for kidney support. Rehmannia is very helpful in protecting the kidneys during kidney failure... I think this is due to not allowing them to take up certain electrolytes, so they do not have to be excreted.

Herbal remedies for arthritis that you could research further are turmeric and yucca which are safe for dogs. Dog must come off Rimadyl.

As far as traditional drugs go, Rimadyl is the oldest and the first. I suggest researching some others. I prefer Metacam. It is generally considered safer, according to my vet, and allows great flexibility in dosing maximum dose on bad days and a maintenance dose other days, as it is a liquid.

In my humble opinion, if you vet is pushing Rimadyl, he is giving what he is getting cheaply and easily. It is one of the oldest and first arthritis drugs and yes, there is evidence it is hard on the liver of labs. I recommend doing some research, discussing, perhaps with a holistic vet or a specialist, acupuncture treats arthritis as well.

You must stop the Rimadyl for a period of time to change to any other medicine. You will need to research this as I do not want to give you the wrong number of days.